# Oracle Error While Select From Temp Global Table in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to create new stored procedure that retrieve data from multiple tables after that update some fields and delete some records after that need to preview data in report.

I created new temporary global table as below :

```
Create Global Temporary Table SC.TmpTable
(F1 date, F2 varchar2(50), F3 number, F4 number, F5 number)
on Commit Delete Rows;
```

After that I created new stored procedure to insert data into TmpTable as below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SC.TEST22
(Date1 In Date, Date2 In Date, QueryOut Out SYS_REFCURSOR) As
Begin
DECLARE C INTEGER;
Begin
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO C FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TmpTable' AND UPPER(OWNER) = 'SC';
  IF C >= 1 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SC.TmpTable';
    COMMIT;
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO SC.TmpTable (F1, F2, F3, F4, F5)
    Select
       A1.F1,
       A1.F2,
       C3.F3,
       0 As F4,
       0 As F5
    From A1
    Inner Join B2 On A1.F2 = B2.F2
    Inner Join C3 On B2.F3 = C3.F3
    Where To_Date(A1.F1) >= To_Date(:1)
        And To_Date(A1.F1) < To_Date(:2)' USING Date1 , Date2; 

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE SC.TmpTable Set F4 = (Select Min(V4) From D4 Where D4.F3 = TmpTable.F3)';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE SC.TmpTable Set F5 = (Select Min(V5) From E6 Where E6.F2 = TmpTable.F2)';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM SC.TmpTable Where F4 = F5)';

   -------------------
   /* Retrieve Data */
   -------------------
   Open Query_Out For
   Select * from SC.TmpTable;
 END IF;
End;
End;
```

Stored Procedure was created successfully. But when I tried to execute it, Error Message appears that it **Object no longer exists "ORA-08103"**.

Although if I replace retrieve statement "Select * from SC.TmpTable" with "Select C From Dual", the value is 1. also, if I remove retrieve Data, stored procedure execute successfully.

Please advise.

Comment: Never use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a date. If you want to match an entire day then either match on a 24-hour range or use the `TRUNC` function to zero the time component of the date.

Comment: What is the point of all the dynamic SQL?  If the table exists, you've made your life more complicated by using dynamic SQL rather than static SQL.  If the table doesn't exist, then the static reference to the table when you open the cursor will fail to compile.  Is there some process that is dropping the temporary table?  A temporary table should be created once and exist forever, just like a permanent table (this is very different from local temporary tables which are commonly created and dropped in a session in other databases).

Comment: There is no need to commit anything after DDL (`truncate`). And  you don't need a dynamic SQL for `truncate` here because temp table is defined as `on commit delete rows`: you may just commit to clear the table. Seems that your "report" is showing the data in separate transaction (there is something that ends current transaction, so leading to temp table cleanup and ORA-08103 error)